# How do I use java.util.Locale as a key somewhere?

Tags: java, locale, equality

`java.util.Locale` is one of those classes where I wonder whether I'm too stupid or the guy who wrote it. Is Mark Davis around?

As far as I can see, this class isn't supposed to be used. The internal cache in the class is private. The factory package private. `equals()` uses `==` to compare strings. This means that I can't compare instances of the class for equality unless I create instances myself, put them into a cache somewhere, violating DRY.

Is this what I should do? Is there a sane explanation for this behavior???

Comment: plus, this class does not implement comparable, so it cannot be used as a Key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because all `String`s passed to the constructors are `intern()`-ed. A questionable practice, but the behaviour is correct in the end.

---

The 3-argument constructor is

```
public Locale(String language, String country, String variant) {
    this.language = convertOldISOCodes(language);
    this.country = toUpperCase(country).intern();
    this.variant = variant.intern();
}
```

and then later on

```
private String convertOldISOCodes(String language) { 
    // we accept both the old and the new ISO codes for the languages whose ISO 
    // codes have changed, but we always store the OLD code, for backward compatibility 
    language = toLowerCase(language).intern();
```

Comment: You're right, I missed that. Unfortunately, equals() still returns false for my test cases.

Comment: Any specific values which fail? I have done a simple test and it passes for me ( just using `new Locale("en","EN")` ).

Comment: Okay, found it: I'm reading the Locales back from Db4o which means they get serialized which breaks the class. Wonderful...

Comment: I've done a small serialisation test which works just fine. See http://gist.github.com/264403 for the actual code.

Comment: Shouldn't you use java.util.Locale.getInstance(String, String, String) anyway?

Comment: @mhaller: That method is package private (-> no one outside java.util can call it) :(

Comment: @Robert: I guess Db4o does something more tricky. I've used a Translator and now it behaves :)

Comment: @Aaron : glad to hear you sorted it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use `locale.toString()` for putting in maps in order to work this around.

Or you can wrap your `Locale` (`class LocaleWrapper { private Locale locale; .. }`), implement the `equals` method properly and then use the wrapper.